# Difference between two dates (datetime)

Tags: python, date, difference, python-datetime

I'm trying to write a program in Python that calculates the number of days between two dates.

I'm getting input from the user in the format May 2 2020. I have learned that I should first parse a string to a date, but I don't know how to do that. Please help me.

Here is the program I have tried:

```
from datetime import date

first_date(input)
sec_date(input)
con_date = datetime.strptime(first_date, '%d %m %Y').date()
con_date2 = datetime.strptime(first_date, '%d %m %Y').date()
delta = con_date2 - con_date
print(delta)
```

If I give input in the form of  string `May 2 2020` for the first_date and `Jun 30 2020` for the sec_date, how can I convert this string into date format? Note: input should be given in the above format only.

The above code is not working for me to convert a string to a date. Please help me convert it into date and find the number of days between sec_date to first_date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply parse the time using the appropriate [strptime format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Then, once you’ve obtained two `date` objects, you can simply subtract them:

```
import datetime 

d1_str = "Apr 29 2020"
d2_str = "May 7 2020"

fmt = "%b %d %Y"

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1_str, fmt).date()
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2_str, fmt).date()

delta = d2 - d1
print(delta)
print(delta.days)
```

Output is:

```
6 days, 0:00:00
6
```

Comment: @ NicolasMWhat should be done to accept the year in both YYYY and YY format. Like 2019 and 19

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime

first_date = "May 2 2020"
sec_date = "Jun 30 2020"
con_date = datetime.strptime(first_date, '%b %d %Y').date()
con_date2 = datetime.strptime(sec_date, '%b %d %Y').date()
delta = con_date2 - con_date
print(delta.days)
```

Comment: Great. Thank you

Comment: What should be done to accept the year in both YYYY and YY format. Like 2019 and 19

Comment: @AshokKumar replace the uppercase %Y with a lowercase %y

Comment: I'm not sure if this will accept both, but that's how you switch between the two formats. If possible, you should have all user inputs formatted the same way. Or you can check to see if the year's format is YYYY or YY and then manipulate the input accordingly.

Comment: @AshokKumar did you figure out how to accept both year formats?

Comment: yeah I modified the code of user Tabulate given below to add another blocks of try and validate to check for %Y and %y. Now it works fine but lengthy code.

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```py
import datetime

str = "May 2 2020"
str2 = "June 30 2020"
#convert str of month to int
str = str.split(" ")
str2 = str2.split(" ")
month_name = str[0]
month_name2 = str2[0]

try:
    datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(month_name, "%B")
except ValueError:
    datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(month_name, "%b")
month_number = datetime_object.month

try:
    datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(month_name2, "%B")
except ValueError:
    datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(month_name2, "%b")
month_number2 = datetime_object.month

#find number of days between dates

d0 = datetime.date(int(str[2]), month_number, int(str[1]))
d1 = datetime.date(int(str2[2]), month_number2, int(str2[1]))
delta = d1 - d0
print(delta.days)
```

Comment: Great program for newbies like me to learn stepwise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to apply that will take for parameters a starting date and an ending date, returning the day difference between them. 
Hope it helps.

```
from datetime import date
import time

first_date = input("Enter First Date: ").split(" ")
sec_date = input("Enter Second Date: ").split(" ")

def getTimeDiff(fist_date, second_date):
    month1 = time.strptime(first_date[0], "%b").tm_mon
    month2 = time.strptime(second_date[0], "%b").tm_mon

    date1 = date(int(fist_date[2]), month1, int(first_date[1]))
    date2 = date(int(second_date[2]), month2, int(second_date[1]))
    delta = date2 - date1
    return delta.days

res = getTimeDiff(first_date, sec_date)
print(res)
```